# Procedure when the color value of pixels in the selected area is changed ( image ROI)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am a novice .. Can anyone of you help me how to set the area of ​​interest (Rui) from the opening image ?? I'm still learning to understand myself from the internet and without any guidance from my lecture .. so stress trying to learn something new without any help..but I do not give up !!!
In fact, it is necessary to specify a region in the picture and make a condition that when you notice any change in pixel color in the selected area when you change the image on the same program,

Comment: You have not specified which image processing tool you are using.

Comment: if you can i need learning about MORE deteals (ROI)